# Using explode method to extract datetime from database

Tags: php

I want to convert a datetime from a database to a timestamp, but it's not working. I changed the `split()` function (deprecated) to `explode()` and still got an error: "Undefined offset: 3".

What am I doing wrong?

```
function createTimestamp($time) {

    list($day, $month, $year, $hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);  // error is here
    return mktime($hour, $minute, -1, $month, $day, $year) + 1492640000000;
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? What's in the `$time` parameter?

Comment: $timei s the CureentTeimeStamp

Comment: errorr is:Undefined offset: 3

Comment: Where does the timestamp  come from and what format does it have? Is it from a database like: `"2019-04-14 23:09:41"`?

Comment: yes exactly, it is from the database table like you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `explode()` only works if the time string *only* uses colons as separators. For a datetime string such as `2019-04-15 23:09:46`, you need to be more clever. You can use a regex to separate the fields:

```
<?php

$time = '2019-04-15 23:09:46';

if (preg_match ('@^(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+) (\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)$@', $time, $m)) {
    list($datettime, $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = $m;
    echo mktime($hour, $minute, -1, $month, $day, $year) + 1492640000000;
} else {
    // Error: malformed string
}

?>
```

The regex above expects at least one digit in each field. If you want to verify the string exactly, you can use a more specific regex such as `@^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d
{2}):(\d{2})$@` to ensure that the number of digits are correct.

You can read more in [PHP Manual: `preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)